# RSelenium webscrape

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website, however the javascript is causing me problems.  I use RSelenium to get to the page I want, and given the html I can parse it and get the data I want.  However it's the step in between that I can't seem to solve.  Here's what I have:

```
library('RSelenium')
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="firefox", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)
library('XML')
url <- "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/Meeting/Results/english/Local/20141012/ST/1"
remDr$navigate(url)
elem <- remDr$findElement(using="div id", value="results")  # PROBLEM HERE, CAN'T FIND A TAG THAT WORKS!
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]  # possible continuation
elemxml <- htmlTreeParse(elemtxt, useInternalNodes=T)
```

(I am after most of the data on the page: the results table, the info just above it, the dividend table and the racing incident report.  But I know how to get that once I have elemxml.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
readHTMLTable(doc)
```

should allow you to access the html and process the tables contained.